# Hot observable with multiple subscribers without loosing any event

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need to have a hot observable which wraps a price feed. This is subscribed  in multiple areas.

The observable is created using Refcount and passed around for subscription.The first subscriber calls subscribe hence starts the stream and get all the events. The second will miss the events until it's subscription and subsequent subscriptions will do the same behaviour.

It is not the missing of events which is my issue. I want all subscribers to get the same data. That is, the stream must start only when the subscription requests are finished.

Is it possible?

Edit: Two approaches and its problems are illustrated below.

1)

```
public void HotObservableSubscriptionWithRefCount()
{       
    var obs1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(x =>
                {
                    var publishVal = x;
                    Console.WriteLine($@"observer1 publishing {publishVal}");
                    return publishVal;
                }).Publish().RefCount();

    var obs2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(x =>
                {
                    var publishVal = x + 100;
                    Console.WriteLine($@"observer2 publishing {publishVal}");
                    return publishVal;
                }).Publish().RefCount();

   var sub1 = obs1.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber1 value {x}"));
                var sub2 = obs2.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber2 
             value {x}"));

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

var combinedSub = obs1.Merge(obs2).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"combined 
              subscriber value {x}"));

  Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

   sub1.Dispose();
   sub2.Dispose();
   combinedSub.Dispose();

   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

Problem: The combined subscriber is missing values from two observables because of the delay in subscription

2)

```
 public void HotObservableSubscriptionWithPublish()
{
    var obs1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(x =>
                {
                    var publishVal = x;
                    Console.WriteLine($@"observer1 publishing {publishVal}");
                    return publishVal;

                }).Publish();

    var obs2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(x =>
                {
                    var publishVal = x + 100;
                    Console.WriteLine($@"observer2 publishing {publishVal}");
                    return publishVal;
                }).Publish();

    var sub1 = obs1.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber1 value 
               {x}"));
    var sub2 = obs2.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($@"subscriber2 value 
               {x}"));

             Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    var combinedSub = obs1.Merge(obs2).Subscribe(x => 
                Console.WriteLine($@"combined subscriber value {x}"));

    obs1.Connect();
    obs2.Connect();

   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

   sub1.Dispose();
   sub2.Dispose();
   combinedSub.Dispose();

   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

This will make sure combinedsubsciber will get values in line with any individual subscribers. However even the subscribers are disposed of, the observer still continue provide values.

I need full life cycle control of publisher and subscriber

Comment: "stream must start only when the subscriptions are finished" doesn't make sense. Subscriptions don't finish. At best they can be cancelled. Can you please provide a [mcve] rather than a vague description?

Comment: Fair point. Addded code

Comment: To second sample: I think disposing the connection should stop the observable from producing values. var conn1 = obs1.Connect() and then conn1.Dispose()

Comment: Usage of Replay extension method suggested. No time for full answer

Comment: Felix, yes the connect functions return disposable was the key

Comment: Do I understand that you just want all values from a hot observerable to be replayed? i.e. making the observable cold?

Comment: A stream is subscribed in many places in the application( a price feed). At the last subscription (which I know) I want all the subscribers to get values. I am not worried about loosing values since the first subscription. However once the stream started all the subscribers should get the same values. Also at some point I want the ability to stop all subscription and stop the stream. Between the subscription start and stop all subscribers should get the same values.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Felix Keil in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326679/hot-observable-with-multiple-subscribers-without-loosing-any-event#comment93552104_53326679), the solution is to use the second approach, and disconnect the connectable observables by disposing the two connections.

```
var conn1 = obs1.Connect();
var conn2 = obs2.Connect();

/* ... */

conn2.Dispose();
conn1.Dispose();
```